# How to find the first of week from a series of dtype('<M8[ns]')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a series `p` of timestamps of type: `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

I am trying to convert it to the first day of the week like so:

```
p - pd.Timedelta(days=p.dt.dayofweek)
```

This clearly is not the right answer

```
TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.
```

but what is?

------------Full stack trace -----------------

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-699-bb55f007b4d9> in <module>()
      2 p= testDf.PlayDate.drop_duplicates()
      3 #p=pd.to_datetime(p)
----> 4 p - pd.to_timedelta(p.dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
      5 

C:\DS\Installs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    607 
    608         time_converted = _TimeOp.maybe_convert_for_time_op(left, right, name,
--> 609                                                            na_op)
    610 
    611         if time_converted is None:

C:\DS\Installs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in maybe_convert_for_time_op(cls, left, right, name, na_op)
    567             return None
    568 
--> 569         return cls(left, right, name, na_op)
    570 
    571 

C:\DS\Installs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in __init__(self, left, right, name, na_op)
    280             left, right = left.align(right, copy=False)
    281 
--> 282         lvalues = self._convert_to_array(left, name=name)
    283         rvalues = self._convert_to_array(right, name=name, other=lvalues)
    284 

C:\DS\Installs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in _convert_to_array(self, values, name, other)
    396             supplied_dtype = values.dtype
    397         inferred_type = supplied_dtype or lib.infer_dtype(values)
--> 398         if (inferred_type in ('datetime64', 'datetime', 'date', 'time') or
    399                 com.is_datetimetz(inferred_type)):
    400             # if we have a other of timedelta, but use pd.NaT here we

TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood
```

Comment: Can you also add data that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is trying to make a single timedelta object out of a series, and so the constructor is failing.

```
p - pd.to_timedelta(p.dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
```

should do what you want.

**Edit:**

Ex:

```
help(pd)
Help on package pandas:

...

VERSION
    0.18.1

...



p = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', '1/23/2017').to_series().reset_index(drop=True)

p.dtype
Out[8]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

print(p.dtype)
datetime64[ns]

p - pd.to_timedelta(p.dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
Out[10]: 
0    2016-12-26
1    2017-01-02
2    2017-01-02
3    2017-01-02
4    2017-01-02
5    2017-01-02
6    2017-01-02
7    2017-01-02
8    2017-01-09
9    2017-01-09
10   2017-01-09
11   2017-01-09
12   2017-01-09
13   2017-01-09
14   2017-01-09
15   2017-01-16
16   2017-01-16
17   2017-01-16
18   2017-01-16
19   2017-01-16
20   2017-01-16
21   2017-01-16
22   2017-01-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(pd.to_timedelta(p.dt.dayofweek, unit='D').dtype)
timedelta64[ns]
```

**Edit2:**

To summarize the comment discussion below, the issue still being experienced was due to an out of date version of pandas. With pandas version greater than `0.18.0`, the solution above should work.

Comment: Thanks this gives the error: `TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood`
I did a `print(p.dtype)` and it gave: `datetime64[ns]` as opposed to just typing `p.type` which gives: `dtype('<M8[ns]')`. Am investigating further to see if I  can figure it out...

Comment: @user1761806 the difference between `print(p.dtype)` & `p.dtype` shouldn't be relevant; I get the same. It's because the `__str__` and `__repr__` differ: `p.dtype.__str__()
Out[241]: 'datetime64[ns]'

p.dtype.__repr__()
Out[242]: "dtype('<M8[ns]')"`, and the difference between the two is just that between general and specific datatypes, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns

Comment: @user1761806 Could you edit your question to include the full stack trace of the current error?

Comment: Done.. I tried to decipher it myself but sadly failed.

Comment: Ok is this perhaps a python bug? The line that fails is: ` if (inferred_type in ('datetime64', 'datetime', 'date', 'time') or` and the reason why it fails is because `inferred_type = datetime64[ns]`

Comment: @user1761806 maybe a pandas bug. What version do you have installed currently? It's working on `0.20.2` and `0.18.1` for me, so if your version is earlier, you could try updating, and if that works we might be able to pin down where/if it changes in the patch notes.

Comment: I have 0.18. The code above works for you then? (Where p is a datetime64[ns] and you are subtracting a timedelta64[ns])?

Comment: Thanks - you helped me figure out the issue. Anaconda python packages were out of date. I needed to do a conda update pandas to update them an now it works! If you post it as an answer I'd be more than happy to award you the points.

Comment: @user1761806 This is my answer that we're commenting on. I've edited in a summary of what we've worked out here though, which should at least make things easier for anyone happening on this later.