# '<M8[ns]' datatype to date - python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe where one column is a datetime in `<M8[ns]` datatype. However, when I use `unique()` it gives me another datatype:

```
array(['2014-10-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-01-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-04-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-07-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-04-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-07-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-10-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-02-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-05-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-08-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-11-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-02-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-05-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-11-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns) says it's the same format, but when I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-datetime-to-date-in-python) to change datetime format to date it gives me an error:

```
df["fecha"].date()
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

There are plenty of solution from string to datetime/date, but I'm looking for a more straightforward solution (datetime to date).

Comment: Did you try converting the array to Series? `pd.Series(whatever[column].unique())`

Comment: pd.Series(whatever[column].unique()).dt.date ?