# Calculating Root-Mean-Square of pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, time, python-3.7

I have 50 residual values that are in the format 00:00:00.0000 under df['Residuals'] but hold actual values in a Pandas dataframe columns such as:

00:00:04.7328

00:00:01.4252

and so on. I want to calculate the rms value of these times in seconds but cannot convert them from this format to just a decimal format. The dtype of the listed values above says m8[ns] which I am unfamiliar with. My question is how can I convert it from this m8[ns] format to an integer and then run the calculations?

Comment: Seems like you have some versioning issues between `pandas` and `numpy`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns

Comment: @ALollz any recommendations then? I updated the numpy and pandas as suggested but nothing has changed.

Comment: Is there a piece of reproducible code anywhere so we can recreate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to be paid attention to is the dtype, whether it's `<m8[ns]` (which is TimedeltaProperties) or `<M8[ns]` (which is DatetimeProperties)

In the case of `<m8[ns]`:

```
df['Residuals'].dt.seconds + df['Residuals'].dt.microseconds*1e-6
```

should get you the answer.

In the case of `<M8[ns]`:

```
df['Residuals'].dt.second + df['Residuals'].dt.microsecond*1e-6 # without 's'
```

should get you the answer.