# When I convert datetime64[ns] column to index its type changes to <M8[ns] and I cannot work with it

Tags: datetime, time-series, datetime-format

I converted a datetime64 column in my dataset to an index. I tried to use it to plot boxplot by month and another one by years. I wasn't able to do it because it appeared that the type of the index is M8[ns]. I tried to change it to datetime64[ns] but it is not possible.

I would appreciate some help here.

```
data.index.year
```

does not work

Comment: check this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns , It is good if you could share sample of your data frame and what you did will help to solve it more precisely than generic answer

Comment: Thank you. I compared the types and my machine says they are equal. In this case, I guess I have to check why the year extraction does not work here.