# Date time conversion to pandas datetime64[updated]

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, datetime-format, numpy-ndarray

I have a series of 40 year data in the format stn;yyyymmddhh:rainfall. I want to convert the data into datetime64 format. When i convert it to datetime with the below code, i get the following format **pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp** But, i need it to be in pandas datetime format. Basically, i want to convert for example 1981010100 which is **numpy.int64** into **datetime64**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = ";")
df['yyyy'] = df['yyyymmddhh'].astype(str).str[:4]
df = pd.to_datetime(data.yyyy, format='%Y-%m-%d')

Stn;yyyymmddhh;rainfall 
xyz;1981010100;0.0
xyz;1981010101;0.0
xyz;1981010102;0.0
xyz;1981010103;0.0
xyz;1981010104;0.0
xyz;1981010105;0.0
xyz;1981010106;0.0
xyz;1981010107;0.0
xyz;1981010108;0.0
xyz;1981010109;0.4
xyz;1981010110;0.6
xyz;1981010111;0.1
xyz;1981010112;0.1
xyz;1981010113;0.0
xyz;1981010114;0.1
xyz;1981010115;0.6
xyz;1981010116;0.0
xyz;1981010117;0.0
xyz;1981010118;0.2
xyz;1981010119;0.0
xyz;1981010120;0.0
xyz;1981010121;0.0
xyz;1981010122;0.0
xyz;1981010123;0.0
xyz;1981010200;0.0
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Comment: please find the sample added

Comment: Please follow linked posting guidelines.

Comment: Hi Dawar, you can also see my solution.  You don't need extra `.dt.strftime` to format the date in your desired format.  The default datetime64 display format is already in your desired format.  If you don't want to modify the existing column `yyyymmddhh`, you can just use another column to hold it.   My solution should be more simple and achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) together with `format=` parameter, as follows:

```
df['yyyymmddhh'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymmddhh'], format='%Y%m%d%H')
```

Output:

```
print(df)

    Stn          yyyymmddhh  rainfall 
0   xyz 1981-01-01 00:00:00        0.0
1   xyz 1981-01-01 01:00:00        0.0
2   xyz 1981-01-01 02:00:00        0.0
3   xyz 1981-01-01 03:00:00        0.0
4   xyz 1981-01-01 04:00:00        0.0
5   xyz 1981-01-01 05:00:00        0.0
6   xyz 1981-01-01 06:00:00        0.0
7   xyz 1981-01-01 07:00:00        0.0
8   xyz 1981-01-01 08:00:00        0.0
9   xyz 1981-01-01 09:00:00        0.4
10  xyz 1981-01-01 10:00:00        0.6
11  xyz 1981-01-01 11:00:00        0.1
12  xyz 1981-01-01 12:00:00        0.1
13  xyz 1981-01-01 13:00:00        0.0
14  xyz 1981-01-01 14:00:00        0.1
15  xyz 1981-01-01 15:00:00        0.6
16  xyz 1981-01-01 16:00:00        0.0
17  xyz 1981-01-01 17:00:00        0.0
18  xyz 1981-01-01 18:00:00        0.2
19  xyz 1981-01-01 19:00:00        0.0
20  xyz 1981-01-01 20:00:00        0.0
21  xyz 1981-01-01 21:00:00        0.0
22  xyz 1981-01-01 22:00:00        0.0
23  xyz 1981-01-01 23:00:00        0.0
24  xyz 1981-01-02 00:00:00        0.0
```

Comment: I just realized that with this method, the column yyyymmddhh is in Timestamps format, but what i actually need is pandas date time format. How do i convert timestamp to datetime

Comment: @Dawar  Where did you see it in Timestamps format ?  You can check the data type by using `df.info()` and refer to the `Dtype` column, you will see its dtype is `datetime64[ns]`.   Also the function used for conversion [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), you can refer to the doc and look at the `Returns` section that for input of a Series: the return type is: `Series of datetime64 dtype` .    This function returns a Timestamp only when you pass it a scalar, i.e. a single element instead of a Series.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I checked it with **type(df.yyyymmddhh[0])**

Comment: @Dawar  No worry!  The date column is still in datetime64 format.  It's just the type() function will see the element type as Timestamp.  You can further check using Pandas property with `df1.yyyymmddhh.dtype` and see the dtype as `dtype('<M8[ns]')` which is a special format of datetime64.  You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218694/15070697) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should fit the bill for you.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = ";")

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymmddhh'], format='%Y%m%d%H')
df['formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Many thanks! The particular column of interest is 'yyyymmddhh'. I received the following error , KeyError: 'Stn;yyyymmddhh;rainfall'

Comment: My mistake! I missed the delimiter. Will change my answer now to reflect this.

Comment: No worries, i sensed that