# getting mean values of dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I can't seem to understand what the difference is between <M8[ns] and date time formats on how these operations relate to why this does or doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 
import numpy as np 

my_dates = ['2021-02-03','2021-02-05','2020-12-25', '2021-12-27','2021-12-12']
my_numbers = [100,200,0,400,500]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':my_dates, 'b':my_numbers})

df['a']=pd.to_datetime(df['a')

# ultimate goal is to be able to go. * df.mean() * and be able to see mean DATE
# but this doesn't seem to work so...

df['a'].mean().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ### ok this works... I can mess around and concat stuff...

# But why won't this work?  

df2 = df.select_dtypes('datetime')
df2.mean() # WONT WORK
df2['a'].mean() # WILL WORK?
```

What I seem to be running into unless I am missing something is the difference between '**datetime**' and '**<M8[ns]**' and how that works when I'm trying to get the mean date.

Comment: Isn't there a warning you get?

Comment: Will adding a line `df2 = df2['a']` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing numeric_only parameter in `mean()` method:

```
out=df.select_dtypes('datetime').mean(numeric_only=False)
```

output of `out`:

```
a   2021-06-03 04:48:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Note:** It will throw you an error If the dtype is string

Comment: Does not work.  After I do any select_dtypes, the operation returns a null output.  This is what I am confused about.

Comment: @runningbirds there is no column with dtype datetime exists that's why you are getting none from `select_dtypes` so convert datetime like values to datetime first then try

Comment: I went and did a work around

Answer (score 0):

mean function you apply is different in each case.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 
import numpy as np 

my_dates = ['2021-02-03','2021-02-05','2020-12-25', '2021-12-27','2021-12-12']
my_numbers = [100,200,0,400,500]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':my_dates, 'b':my_numbers})

df['a']=pd.to_datetime(df['a'])
df.mean()
```

This mean function its the DataFrame mean function, and it works on numeric data. To see who is numeric, do:

```
df._get_numeric_data()

    b
0   100
1   200
2   0
3   400
4   500
```

But df['a'] is a datetime series.

```
df['a'].dtype, type(df)
(dtype('<M8[ns]'), pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)
```

So df['a'].mean() apply different mean function that works on datetime values. That's why df['a'].mean() output the mean of datetime values.

```
df['a'].mean()
Timestamp('2021-06-03 04:48:00')
```

read more here:
[difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206612/difference-between-data-type-datetime64ns-and-m8ns)
[DataFrame.mean() ignores datetime series
#28108](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28108)

Comment: Yes, I get this, but this isn't answering the question I was trying to ask.   WHY does df['a'].mean() work just fine, but if I do df.select_dtypes('datetime').mean() NOT WORK?  After I **select_dtypes**, the format changes from <m8[ns] to datetime which DOES NOT appear to support any more calculations.  How do I handle this?

Comment: why do you need the select_dtypes for ?