# Python FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object'

Tags: python, pandas, types, timestamp

When I try to create an empty series:

```
my_series = pd.Series()
```

I am prompted to use an explicit datatype:

```
FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object'
instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly
to silence this warning.
```

In the series, I will store pandas timestamps, which I don't know what's the string to use for the dtype. I can't find it. How can I remove those annoying warnings?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `datetime64[ns]`.

```
my_series = pd.Series(dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Proof:

```
>>> date_series = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('today')])
>>> str(date_series.dtype)
'datetime64[ns]'
```

For completeness: You *could* also use `<M8[ns]`, but that's much less understandable (in my opinion), and [less portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218694/17242583), therefore I highly recommend `datetime64[ns]` instead.