# How to update "usual" datetime64[ns] values with some '<M8[ns]' values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I [know a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29206612/4865723) about the different types of datetime objects in numpy but I don't fully understand it.

I want to use `pandas.DataFrame.update()` to update a timestamp column with some values of timestamps from another dataframe. The dtype of the "other" timestamps is `<M8[ns]`. When I update the original dataframe with that values the result are not timestamps but just big integers like `1444435200000000000`.

The MWE does **not** reproduce the error because I don't know how to generate `<M8[ns]` values.

So the **main** question is how can I deal with that problem to update a timestamp column with timestamps of "different" types?

The **secondary** question would be how such `<M8[ns]` timestamps are generated? Maybe I can find the place in my code where they are created. Currently I just do `pandas.to_datetime(arg=df.time_strings, format='%Y-%m-%d')`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# !!! The MWE does **not** reproduce the error because
# !!! I don't know how to generate `<M8[ns]` values.

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2],
    'A': [
        pd.Timestamp('2022-09-11 19:04:47'),
        pd.Timestamp('2022-09-11 11:57:39'),
    ]})
print(df.A.dtype)  # dtype('O')


x = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [2],
    'A': [
        pd.Timestamp('2016-09-11 00:01:22'),  # this should be of type "<M8[ns]"
    ]})

print(x.A.dtype)  # dtype('<M8[ns]')

df.update(x)
print(df)
```

Comment: which pandas version did you use? This works fine on 1.4.4

Comment: The MWE does **not** reproduce the error because I don't know how to generate `<M8[ns]` values.

Comment: How did you generate the issue in the first place?

Comment: Can't answer that here. To complexe in productive code. I wasn't able to reproduce (generate <M8[ns] values) in an MWE.

Comment: Date/time is represented as nanosecond since the Unix epoch by the datetime64[ns] types. For instance 1444435200000000000 is Oct 10 2015 00:00 UTC - so if you end up with integers, you can just convert back to datetime.

Comment: btw. could this be a matter of how things are *shown* in your output? - try `print(repr(x.A.dtype), str(x.A.dtype))` to see what I mean. Also noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242219/10197418) to the Q&A you linked.